# Automatic redirect of unauthenticated users

Tags: c#, authentication, owin, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have a site which uses OpenID Connect OWIN middleware to authenticate users from an Azure Active Directory tenant.  Is it possible to redirect an unauthenticated user to the Azure AD login page automatically, without them having to first hit a protected endpoint or click a sign in button?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Redirect on what request?

Comment: Upon requesting the initial page.  Typically they're redirected once they try to hit a REST endpoint to perform some action, but I want them to be redirected as soon as they first visit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With skipping `Home Realm discovery` this will work, sending all users to a single AD. If ADFS is configured correctly and the user is signed in onto the domain, true Single Sign On is performed, otherwise the company login page is displayed.

If you have a mixed set of users(different AD domains), all users will be sent to the same AD login page.

From Vittorio's post:
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/17/skipping-the-home-realm-discovery-page-in-azure-ad/

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = clientId,
    Authority = authority,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) => 
        {                                                        
            context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = "mydomain.com"; 
            return Task.FromResult(0); 
        }, 
    }
});
```